# VS Desktop Express 2012 - Hide components at design time

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have not been able to find a proper solution or answer for this.

I have lots of elements (buttons, labels, ...) that I need to add into a form; I am doing this at design time.
Can I hide certain of these elements at DESIGN time?

For example, I have a tableLayoutPanel with 12 rows. As I add and add elements into the rows, at some point the tableLayoutPanel extends the form and I have to resize again and again the form and the panel and so on as it grows.

Appreciate any answers,
best regards
Dennis

Comment: Get a bigger screen :P

Comment: can you please tell what kind of application this is? Is it C# / C++ Html?

Comment: The "bigger screen" answer is what I supposed to happen :) - I'm using C# and WinForms (but does that matter?)